# XCode keeps forgetting imported Frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I have Xcode 6.3, using Swift, importing a Parse 1.7.1 Framework as usual (dragging, copying) and I set it up in a group: Frameworks.

I compile and everything works fine for a while with it, until the compiler does not recognize this sentence anymore:

```
import Parse
```

It gives me the error:

```
No such module 'Parse'
```

A workaround is to delete the Framework and copy it again, but after a while it starts getting annoying, and I would really like to know the cause.

I only code and build in the meantime (and occasionally creating new swift files), so I can't explain why this happens.

Comment: Is Parse in objective c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just fixed this same issue today with my project.  I imported my obj-c framework in a swift project and it worked for a while, then xcode seemed to forget it causing the same error you have.

[apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75)

I fixed it by referencing the bridging header in Build Settings.

> Under Build Settings, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header build
>   setting under Swift Compiler - Code Generation has a path to the
>   header. The path should be relative to your project, similar to the
>   way your Info.plist path is specified in Build Settings. In most
>   cases, you should not need to modify this setting.

I just typed in the name of the bridging header folderName/xxxx-BridgingHeader.h in the field that states bridging header and all was well again.

Answer (score 5):

If you're targeting `iOS 8` and above, you can tell `Cocoapods` to use frameworks, by putting

```
use_frameworks!
```

in your `Podfile`, like this example:

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

# Parse
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7'
```

I could fix the same problem by doing so.