# No such module 'Parse' following Parse iOS Swift Quickstart guide

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Following the "quick" start guide here https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/new

I've read and tried several suggestions from related SO questions, like here [Connect Objective C framework to Swift iOS 8 app (Parse framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272184/connect-objective-c-framework-to-swift-ios-8-app-parse-framework) and here
[No Such Module 'Parse'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663180/no-such-module-parse), and here [XCode keeps forgetting imported Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021117/xcode-keeps-forgetting-imported-frameworks)

Maybe I've done something wrong with the bridging headers..

The project builds but it still shows the no module error in ViewController.swift and Parse is not autocompleting.

Comment: How much targets do you have in project? I had the same problem after upgrade to Xcode7-beta. I had two targets. One target was building correct, another one started showing 'No such module Parse'. I fix that by removing another target, and creating new one by cloning first target that was building correctly.

Comment: I am also on Xcode7-beta.  I only see one target though, ParseStarterProject

Comment: May be try to remove your target and scheme, after that create new one. Not sure that it will help.

Comment: Can you show your project in xcode and the code which fails?

Comment: Hey guys, pretty new to iOS (not even sure how to delete the target and scheme) I deleted the project and tried again... still no luck.  All you do to recreate it is go to this link for a parse example project, follow steps 1 & 2 and then look in ViewController.swift and you'll see an error on the "import Parse" line... thanks so much for the help https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/new

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

Go to your Project -> Build Settings > Search Paths > Framework Search Paths

and Add this $(PROJECT_DIR)

Now copy the Parse Frameworks to your Project Folder!

its will Works! :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irc1B.png)

Answer (score 0):

- Simply add a new **Objective-C** File to your project then Xcode will prompt whether you want to configure your project with a bridging header , so press "**Create Bridging Header**" button so that your project will configure combination of **Swift** and **Objective-C** code.
- Now Make sure that you have **import** Parse framework in your ViewController file and then build your application and run it.
- If still not working then just closed your project and reopen it and run again.