# Framework Search Paths

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've been using the Parse SDK and it's worked just fine but all day today, I've gotten an error: "No module Parse."

In build settings, where should my Frame Search Path be? Right now I have it pointing to the file where the Frameworks are contained but I also have the frameworks in my project files.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: try to set framework search path to $(SRCROOT) . go to build settings->search paths->framework search path.

Comment: Could this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021117/xcode-keeps-forgetting-imported-frameworks) help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 22):

I initially had the same issue. It was non-obvious to me that xCode has tabs to control the extent to which 'Build Settings' are displayed. You have to select the'All' tab as shown in attached screen shot.

[image: Hopefully this image helps!]

Hope this helps save others future frustration! Stay awesome folks!

Answer (score 1):

To set framework search path in Xcode: select your target -> Build Setting -> Search Path-> Framework Search Paths. Double click it will show Search Paths input text view

read more : [Framework not found MicrosoftBandKit_iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744761/framework-not-found-microsoftbandkit-ios/30745571#30745571)
it's same problem